# Excell VBA Error for and unknown reason

Tags: vba, runtime

I want to copy some cells into a different workbook. It's VBA in excel and it runtime error 1004

```
Sub sortout()
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$BD$336").AutoFilter Field:=7
Dim i As Integer
i = 4
Dim top As Integer
top = Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
While i < top
    If InStr(Cells(i, 7), "Daimler AG") = 0 Then
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        i = i - 1
        top = top - 1
    ElseIf InStr(Cells(i, 17), "MAJOR") = 0 Then
        If InStr(Cells(i, 17), "SIGNIFICANT") = 0 Then
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            i = i - 1
            top = top - 1
        End If
        'Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend
Rows(2).EntireRow.Delete
Range("A:G,I:O,R:V,Z:AA,AC:BD").Delete

Columns("C:C").Cut Destination:=Columns("H:H")
Columns("B:B").Cut Destination:=Columns("C:C")
Columns("H:H").Cut Destination:=Columns("B:B")
Range("C1").EntireColumn.Insert
Range("H1").EntireColumn.Insert
ChDir "C:\Users\antgal\Desktop"
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\antgal\Desktop\Reported_Changes_Daimler_CW27.xlsx"
    Windows("Copy of Minutes - Changes_ITO_QGATE_2016-07-06.xlsx").Activate
    Range("A3:I5").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Reported_Changes_Daimler_CW27.xlsx").Activate
    Range("B6:J7").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there any message that goes with the error? 1004 isn't helpful. Maybe a line number?

Comment: You can edit your question and replace it with the correct code.

Comment: Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error // All I can see is that it goes through all opens the workbook but doesnt copy anything :S so it must be in the last 5 lines...

Comment: try to debug the code and tell us, at which line you get that error

Comment: Its the ActiveSheet.Paste line

Comment: Change `Windows` to `Workbooks` and try it?

Comment: Oh and avoid using `.Select` and `.Activate` and `.Paste` wherever you can as it will slow the performance right down.  You pretty much never need to use these anyway.

Comment: I tried but still the same error at the same line :S btw what should I use instead? Im pretty new to VBA

Answer (score 0):

Try with below. It will work

**Note:** Copy and Destination should be equal. Thats the problem here.

```
Workbooks("Copy of Minutes - Changes_ITO_QGATE_2016-07-06.xlsx").Sheets("Enter your sheet name to copy").Range("A3:I5").copy Workbooks("Reported_Changes_Daimler_CW27.xlsx").Sheets("Enter your sheet name to copy").Range("B6")
```

Kindly replace your sheets name with "Enter your sheet name to copy"

Comment: Tried and now it says: Run-time error 438: Object doesnt support this property or method on this line Windows("Copy of Minutes - Changes_ITO_QGATE_2016-07-06.xlsx").Activate

Comment: Changed Windows to Workbooks and now it says the run-time error again at ActiveSheet.Paste

Comment: You forgot .Paste from the end but if I add it then returns the same error 438  Object doesnt support this property or method on the .Paste line

Comment: .paste is not necessary for that line. can you please post your excel through dropbox? so that i will fix that issue

Comment: this was missing from your code:  ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Workbooks("Reported_Changes_Daimler_CW27.xlsx").Sheets("To report").Range("B6:I7") I got it solved ! Thank you!